# If 2 is a primitive root of $p$, is it also a primitive root of $p^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $2$ is a primitive root of an odd prime $p$, is it also a primitive root of $p^2$?

**Edit:** For the first 10,000 primes $p$, Wolfram|Alpha [confirmed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Select%5BPrime%5BRange%5B10000%5D%5D,%20MultiplicativeOrder%5B2,%23%5D%20=%20EulerPhi%5B%23%5D%20%26%5D%20=%20Select%5BPrime%5BRange%5B10000%5D%5D,%20MultiplicativeOrder%5B2,%23%5E2%5D%20=%20EulerPhi%5B%23%5E2%5D%20%26%5D) that $2$ is a primitive root of $p$ if and only if $2$ is also a primitive root of $p^2$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is open or not. In any case, there doesn't seem to be any known counter-examples to this problem as listed [here](http://oeis.org/A055578). None of the numbers on the list have $2$ as the least primitive root.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** This answer is not complete. It may not even be correct. But it has generated too many comments for me to remove it, and it may at least be of interest as an avenue of proof that doesn't work (unless someone can fix it). So I am leaving it up.

Clearly, since $2^k\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$ implies $2^k\equiv 1\bmod p$, the period of $2$ modulo $p^2$ must be a multiple of the period modulo $p$, i.e., $p-1$. On the other hand, the period must divide $\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)$, so it must equal $p(p-1)$ unless it equals $p-1$, in which case $p^2\mid 2^{p-1}-1$.

But if it is, then $p^2\mid (2^{(p-1)/2}-1)(2^{(p-1)/2}+1)$. $p$ does not divide the first factor by assumption, so $2^{(p-1)/2}\equiv-1\bmod p^2$ … and the conclusion is still not clear.

Comment: “I thought I was wrong once, but I was mistaken.”

Comment: $p$ and $p^2$ cannot divide $2^k$...

Comment: You mean $p^2\mid (2^k-1)$ and $p^2\mid\(2^{p-1}-1)$ and $p\mid (2^{(p-1)/2}-1)$, etc. Is there anything special about $2$ in this proof?

Comment: @anon That's what he probably means, but then the implication $p^2\mid(2^{p-1}-1) \Rightarrow p\mid (2^{(p-1)/2}-1)$ is not obvious...

Comment: @N.S. Yeah, that is also true. Maybe I was mistaken when I thought I was mistaken about being wrong. Let me think for a moment.

Comment: @N.S. $p^2\mid (2^{(p-1)/2}+1)(2^{(p-1)/2}-1)$ implies either $p^2\mid (2^{(p-1)/2}+1)$, i.e. $2^{(p-1)/2}\equiv-1~(p^2)$ so $2$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$, or else $p\mid (2^{(p-1)/2}-1)$ so $2^{(p-1)/2}\equiv1~(p)$ i.e. $2$ is not a primitive root mod $p$. I think this is the reasoning.

Comment: @anon but then wouldn't this proof work for any prime number? And by Dirichclet Theorem, wouldn't we get that any primitive root mod $p$ is automatically a primitive root mod $p^2$, which cannot be true?

Comment: @anon What do you mean by $2^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{p^2}$ so $2$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$?

Comment: @EuYu yea, i missed it, that is the mistake :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that that must be the mistake (and we know an error exists because $2$ is not special in this argument). Being a primitive root mod $p^2$ means $2^{p(p-1)/2}\equiv-1~(p^2)$, not $2^{(p-1)/2}\equiv-1~(p^2)$.

Comment: As is evident by the quality of my thinking, it's past my bedtime. So I am going to bed now, and will leave you good people to finish tearing apart my attempt. Or better yet, come up with something that does work. Oy, forgot to upvote the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\text{if $\,2\,$ is a primitive root modulo $\,p\,$ and }\;\;2^{p-1}\neq 1\pmod{p^2}$$

$$\,\,\text{then $\,2\,$ is a primitive root modulo}\,\,p^2$$

In case $\,2^{p-1}=1\pmod{p^2}\,$ no problem: $\,2+p\,$ is a primitive root modulo $\,p^2\,$

Spoiler!

> Read the first part of this [paper](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.dartmouth.edu%2F~m25f11%2Fnotes%2Fclass24.pdf&ei=duRlUc6RIeKn0wX4pIGIBg&usg=AFQjCNFx-g8KaLmn2bkaXA6FQhj-a0BEzg&sig2=AucL-G_ltllifLfIHSrkdQ)

Comment: I'm puzzled by this, but my brain seems to have turned to mush anyhow.

Comment: It's a general thing, @HaraldHanche-Olsen . Read the paper in the spoiler.

Comment: You should say "if 2 is a primitive root modulo $p$" rather than "of order $p$", since "order" has a well-established meaning that directly clashes with this.

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Comment: My problem was (and is) that this does not seem to solve the problem. All the papers shows is that $2$ or $2+p$ is primitive modulo $p^2$, which is a fine result in the right direction but still insufficient to answer the given question. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: I'm with you on this.

Comment: No @HaraldHanche-Olsen, you are right: not always is possible (for me, of course) to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected (I think) that there are infinitely many counterexamples, but that's not known. In general, there's no reason to expect that a given primitive root modulo $p$ should always be a primitive root modulo $p^2$.

(Originally I claimed that we actually know two counterexamples, [1093 and 3511](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime); but that's wrong - 2 is a cube modulo 1093 and a square modulo 3511, hence not a primitive root for either prime.)

Comment: Ha! I was seconds away from posting a wrong answer. Thank you. +1.

Comment: @GregMartin: 2 is not a primitive root of either 1093 or 3511, so these are not counterexamples.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: Are you certain that your answer was wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Now I see that I might not have been wrong. Let me try to reconstruct it.

Comment: @Billy is right: 2 is a cube modulo 1093 and a square modulo 3511. How annoying, since I'm pretty sure I'm on the right side of the argument generally, but now I've got no witnesses....